# Unpacking a zip object causing ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zip

I created a zip object using the following line of code:

```
k=zip([1,2,3],['a','b','c'])
```

Converting this into a list gives the output:

```
[(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')]
```

However, when I use this line of code

```
x,y=zip(*k)
```

it gives me this ValueError:

```
"ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)"
```

I've been trying to find out what the problem is but couldn't figure anything out.

Comment: it's working for me. did you get the error with same example you posted

Comment: You can't consume the iterator twice.

Comment: There must be something else wrong with your code. I converted your problem into a one-liner and that works fine. Please run the one-liner and confirm whether it works for you or not: `zip(*list(zip([1,2,3],['a','b','c'])))`

Comment: Yes I did  @komatiraju032.

Comment: Please take a look at your list conversion. You seem to apply zip(*) to k, which is not the list, but the original result of zip(). If you convert it to a list it will become a copy, so you will have to unzip your list, not k.

Comment: This works for me, apparently it also works if I use the line right after creating the zip object, but not if I use it for something else before that. As the comment before yours points out @Cerno. Yep your second comment also seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a full running example that raises the error? The error suggests that you are using the iterator twice - its empty the second time - but we are only guessing until you post it. BTW, try `list(k)` twice and you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns a iterator, so when you print it, you consume it so after that `k` is empty

- apply the second `zip` directly

  ```
  k = zip([1,2,3],['a','b','c'])
  x,y = zip(*k)
  print(x, "/", y) # (1, 2, 3) / ('a', 'b', 'c')
  ```
- wrap it in a `list` to use it multiple times

  ```
  k = list(zip([1,2,3],['a','b','c']))
  print(k)         # [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
  x,y = zip(*k)
  print(x, "/", y) # (1, 2, 3) / ('a', 'b', 'c')
  ```